# who to believe google analytics or internal logs

Tags: logging, google-analytics

Don't get it my internal logs say that I have 10,671 vists
and google analytics say that I only have 1,277 users fo the day (yesterday).

My internal logs say that I have

```
Internal Logs
301,918 hits
264,033 files
63,695 pages
10,671 visits
4,644 sites

Google analytics
Users 1,277
New Users 1,052
Sessions 1,770
Number of Sessions per User 1.39
Pageviews 3,123
Pages / Session 1.76
```

Who is lying? both are of the same day

Comment: Why do you think someone is lying? How did you analyze your internal logs?

Comment: google analytics is installed in the index only and the logs are fo ethe whole site, so how many unique vistors do I have?

Comment: G filters out bots, users who have not waited for js to load, users who have js disabled in browser etc. Both of these stats are correct for different segments of your site visitors.

Answer (score 3):

Google Analytics, and indeed most analytics tracking, identifies unique users that have js enabled. A single user will make many requests in a session. See their help articles:  [How users are identified for users metrics](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/2992042?hl=en)

It is possible some users never see the index. You could do analysis of your own to tell how many unique IP addresses per day, and if any of them never hit the analytics. Import your logs to a database, for example.

Assuming the data is "lying" is usually healthy skepticism. But you do need to do research on how data is collected and the statistics calculated.

[Webmasters Stack Exchange naturally has questions tagged Google Analytics.](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/google-analytics) You may find insight there.